# Redirecting all requests to domain except for some folders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I try to redirect all requests from a domain to a subdomain, except for `/mypath` and all stuff below.
Examples:

```
example.com -> sub.example.com
example.com/somestuff -> sub.example.com
```

but
    `example.com/my-path` should not be redirected.

Here's the configuration part responsible for that:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my-path/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/sub\.example\.com" [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that I cannot achieve the goal and I have no idea what is wrong here. I have tried to find an example of that to achieve the same goal but no luck.

Comment: "I cannot achieve the goal" - What is happening exactly? Any redirection, the wrong redirection, errors?

Comment: wrong redirection - the exclude is also redirected, but shouldn't be.

Comment: And what about @Brandon's solution - does this work for you or not? (Bearing in mind you will need to clear any local caches, since the redirect prior to implementing this _exception_ will have been cached hard by the browser.)

Comment: no, @Brandon's solution didn't solve the problem and it doesn't matter if I try `/my-path/something/else.php` or just `/my-path/`, all gets redirected as if there were no exceptions made.

Comment: Is `/my-path` a physical directory on the filesystem? If so, do you have any other `.htaccess` files in this subdirectory? Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: yes, it's physical folder on fs, no other `.htaccess` files - none I'm aware of, yes - common rules generated by WordPress are in the `.htaccess`.
If it will help, I will edit post, adding configurations I have tried - there is one with common `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` for WP default rules + my above 3 lines and second, where above lines are in separate, preceding `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` directive

Answer (score 1):

Putting a trailing slash will match only when the URI `/my-path/` is typed and not `/my-path`

Use

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my-path
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/sub\.example\.com" [R=301,L]
```

so that it will math both `/my-path/` and `/my-path`